# how to skip the files in the specific patteren in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one folder in this folder contain different kind of files like

```
qt_fact_info.d20140228
qt_fact_info_is.d20140228
qt_fact_info_bkk.d20140228
qt_fact_info_lb.d20140228
qt_fact_info_sg.d20140228
```

I want only `qt_fact_info.d20140228` this type of files only. I don't want files matching these patterns: `*_is,*_bkk,*_lb,*_sg`

Please help me how to print the above required kind of files(qt_fact_info.d20140228) by using UNIX shell scripting

Comment: Umm, `ls *_info.*`? What do you mean "print by using UNIX shell scripting" - do you really mean _a bash script_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ls | grep -v '_is\|_bkk\|_lb\|_sg'
```

- `grep -v` prints everything that does not match the pattern.
- `\|` means or
- `ls |` sends the output of ls to grep for filtering.